# Get last n lines of file -- decoding error

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, tail, utf

I have a `utf-16` file I'm trying to read the last few lines of. Here is what I have now:

```
def get_last_n_lines(self, n, file=None):
    '''
    Sorted from the bottom to the top.
    '''
    file = file or self.file
    s = subprocess.check_output(['tail', '-%s' % str(n), file]).decode('utf-8')
    return
```

However, I get the following error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position 4607: invalid start byte

Even if I do `.decode('utf-16')` it gives me an error. What would be the proper way to get the last 100 lines of the file from the tail command?

Answer (score 2):

What worked was to add a more general unicode encoding in the decode method:

```
> s = subprocess.check_output(['tail', '-%s' % str(n), file]).decode('unicode_escape')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add encoding="437" or encoding="850".